# Is it possible to use CSS custom property within the definition of the Sass variable, and if so, how?

Tags: css, variables, sass

this is my first question here, so please be patient if I am doing something wrong :)

I have some weird problem and I still haven't found a solution, even though I've spent a few hours searching on Google.

So I have a CSS custom property called `--vh` that I set up dynamically with JavaScript.

In order to make life easier and not write all this long syntax with the var every time, I wanted to create the Sass variable called $vh and use it wherever I need it:

```
$vh: var(--vh, 1vh);
$m-distance: $vh * 2;
$input-height: $m-distance * 1.6;
$sm-distance: $m-distance * 0.5;
$l-distance: $m-distance * 1.6;
$xl-distance: $m-distance * 2;
// And there are dosens of places in my app where I later use these variables...
```

But when I do that right away in the next line I get an error:

```
SassError: Undefined operation: "var(--vh, 1vh) times 2".
        on line 21 of src/styles/setup/_variables.scss
        from line 4 of /home/joisadler/github/fymdaily/client/src/styles/global.scss
>> $m-distance: $vh * 2;
   -------------^
```

And if for example instead of `$vh: var(--vh, 1vh);` I write just `$vh: 1vh;`, everything passes successfully.  But this is not what I want because I need my `vh` to be rather dynamic.

I have found lots of explanations for the reverse case when I want to use the Sass variable within the custom property definition.  But I need to do the exact opposite and use custom property within the definition of the Sass variable.

Does anyone have any idea how to do such things?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now come up with a pretty simple solution on how to do what I wanted, I checked and it really works great.
First of all I defined all my variables as custom properties:

```css
// _base.scss
:root {
 // --vh property itself defined dynamically by JavaScript
 --m-distance: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 2.5);
 --input-height: calc(var(--m-distance) * 1.6);
 --sm-distance: calc(var(--m-distance) * 0.5);
 --l-distance: calc(var(--m-distance) * 1.6);
 --xl-distance: calc(var(--m-distance) * 2);
}
```

And after that I just defined sass variables with the same names:

```css
// _variables.scss
$m-distance: var(--m-distance);
$input-height: var(--input-height);
$sm-distance: var(--sm-distance);
$l-distance: var(--l-distance);
$xl-distance: var(--xl-distance);
```

And now I enjoy two worlds: also get the `--vh` property dynamically from JavaScript and can also use Sass variables with shorter and nicer syntax in all the other files in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following on https://www.sassmeister.com/ and it seems to work.

Input

```
:root {
    --vh: 10vh;
}

$var: var(--vh, 1vh);

body {
    height:$var;
}
```

Output

```css
:root {
  --vh: 10vh;
}

body {
  height: var(--vh, 1vh);
}
```

Have you tried declaring a default value for --vh inside the Sass file so the compiler recognises it and doesn't produce an error?

Comment: The code that you wrote really does not cause errors, errors appear when I try to perform calculations with this variable, like this: `$m-distance: $vh * 2;`

Comment: Of course, I can use interpolation like this: `$m-distance: calc(#{$vh} * 2);` but I have dozens of places in my app where I use variables based on this `vh` variable and it's very hard now to do such in all the places :( Maybe there is a way to do it at the definition itself?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would make this easier at this point. Back to the drawing board for me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, but not to calculate with SASS functions

Why assign a SASS variable to the value of a CSS custom property? For calculations (as in your question) and useful built-in functions like `color.scale()`. You won't be able to use these tools with values derived from CSS custom properties.

```scss
@use "sass:color";
:root {
    --basic_color: #FF0000;                             // Red
}

$sassy_color: var(--basic_color, #00FF00);              // Red with green fallback
$pure_color: #FF0000;                                   // Red

body {
    background-color: $sassy_color;                     // ✅ Red background
    color: color.scale($pure_color, $lightness: +90%);  // ✅ Red text, or 
    color: color.scale($sassy_color, $lightness: +90%); //  Error: not a color
}
```

As [Josh Bonnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14481105/josh-bonnick) shows, you *can* put a CSS custom property insertion statement into a SASS variable, as in `background-color: $sassy-color`, but that's not very useful; it might as well be a custom property insertion. Unfortunately, this is only a string, and SASS won't evaluate the `var()` function call.

Let's say we want to change the lightness of the color, as in `color: color.scale()`. If our SASS variable uses a color primitive (`$pure_color`), it works as intended, but if we use a variable that represents an CSS custom property (`$sassy_color`), it fails, because it can't do math on the string `var(--basic_color, #00FF00);`.

### So why do it? Organization

In a beautiful [SASS architecture proposal](https://dev.to/felipperegazio/css-custom-properties-vars-with-sass-scss-a-practical-architecture-strategy-1m88), [Felippe Regazio](https://github.com/felippe-regazio) lays out a method for making CSS custom properties his styling modules using SASS functions as getters and setters. This is essentially all string manipulation, and it shows how useful it can be to access CSS custom properties with SASS variables even if you're not going to use them for calculations.

```
/**
 * Retrieve a css variable value with prefix
 *  
 * Usage
 *  
 * .selector {
 *   color: get(primary-color);
 * }
 * 
 * Will result in
 * 
 * .selector {
 *    color: var(--prefix-primary-color);
 * }
 */
@function get($name, $prefix: pm) {
    @return var(--#{$prefix}-#{$name});
}
/**
 * Update a css variable value
 *
 * Instead of 
 *
 * .selector {
 *   --#{$prefix}-button-height: 56px;
 * }
 *
 * Usage
 *
 * .selector {
 *   @include set(button-height, 56px);
 * }
 */
@mixin set ($name, $value: '', $prefix: pm) {
    --#{$prefix}-#{$name}: #{$value};
}
```

[Read the article](https://dev.to/felipperegazio/css-custom-properties-vars-with-sass-scss-a-practical-architecture-strategy-1m88) for more details.